# Moment ISO Deprecation console Warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

**I am facing the below warning,**

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format.
> moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable
> across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged
> and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to
> http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
> Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true,
> _l: undefined, _i: 2016-9-26 19:30, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

When trying to do this using moment,

```
let startDate = "2022-11-29T11:30:00Z"
let currentDate = moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm")
```

I need to find the difference between the startDate and currentDate in hours. So firstly i tried formatting startDate like this,

```
let formatStartDate = moment(startDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm")
```

And tried finding diff like this,

```
let diffTime = moment(formatStartDate).diff(currentDate,"hours").
```

So, how should I refactor this code and get rid of that warning, any suggestions please ?

Comment: Is this code for a new project or to support an existing app?

Comment: @Yogi, to support an existing app

Comment: Why are you formatting and then parsing what is essentially the same value? `moment(startDate).diff(currentDate, "hours")`

Answer (score 1):

You re-format the parsed start date right again and use the formatted string for the comparison. Remove the `.format(...)` calls altogether or move formatting to the latest possible place, if you need to print the time:

```
// set the current date in the IST timezone (+05:30)
let currentDate = moment().utcOffset(5*60 + 30);

// set the start date for comparison, also in IST timezone
let startDate = moment("2022-11-29T11:30:00Z").utcOffset(5*60 + 30);

// get the difference between the two as number in hours
let diffTime = startDate.diff(currentDate, "hours");

console.log(`There are ${diffTime} hours between ${startDate.format()}
and ${currentDate.format()}.`);
```

Comment: If I want the startDate and currentDate to be converted in IST timezone and then find the difference between them ?

Comment: Then you can use the dedicated `.utcOffset()` method: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/ Formatting is done at the very last moment, when you want to display a time value or send it to the server.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding it properly, could you please provide an example or edit the post?

Comment: I’ve updated the answer. Is it a bit clearer now?